# Java fx fxml generation

Tags: javafx-2, fxml

I am working on JavaFX . I have a java file that includes the design configuration.I need to write the same as an fxml file,that java FX allows.For eg:

```
GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
Label label = new Label();
label.setText("My Label"); 
GridPane.setRowIndex(label, 0);
GridPane.setColumnIndex(label, 0);
gridPane.getChildren().add(label);
```

The Fxml equivalents is:

```
<GridPane>
    <children>
        <Label text="My Label">
        <GridPane.rowIndex>0</GridPane.rowIndex>
        <GridPane.columnIndex>0</GridPane.columnIndex>
        </Label>
    </children>
</TabPane>.
```

Now I am using more than one layouts like vbox,hbox along with gridpane.how can i generate the fxml for that?
Java code is given below.Please help in generating its fxml.

```
VBox vBox = new VBox();
vBox.setSpacing(10);
vBox.setPadding(new Insets(60, 0, 0, 20));
vBox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
HBox hbox= new HBox();
hbox.setPadding(new Insets(1,0,0,770));
hbox.setSpacing(2);
hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
GridPane homegrid = new GridPane();
homegrid.setPadding(new Insets(100, 100, 90, 50));
homegrid.setVgap(5);
homegrid.setHgap(5);
Button employee = new Button("");
employee.setUserData(Font.BOLD);
employee.setMinSize(100, 100);
homegrid.setConstraints(employee, 10,10);


homegrid.getChildren().addAll(employee,shop,product,datamanager,leave,users);


rootGroup.getChildren().addAll(vb);
rootGroup.getChildren().addAll(homegrid,hbox);
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way now is to try Oracle's SceneBuilder -- new UI design tool for JavaFX. You design app by visual tool and will get FXML as a result.

Public beta was released yesterday: http://fxexperience.com/2012/04/announcing-javafx-scene-builder-public-beta/